# How access properties of buttons from outside an outlet - Swift

Tags: swift, uibutton, iboutlet

I have a scene which displays a question from an array. The storyboard includes two buttons to go to the next/previous question. I have a method which asks the class holding the questions (Deck) for the current chapter, current question and number of total questions. This is used to update the title.

I would like to be able to use my updateTitle() func to be able to control the enabled status of my two buttons - disabling the 'next' button when the current question is the last one and disabling the 'previous' button when the first question is being displayed.

I am able to change the status of a button from within its outlet e.g. by calling sender.isEnable = false with a relevant if statement. But the problem with this is that if a user clicks next to the point that the button becomes disabled, clicking the previous button doesn't re-enable the 'next' button.

What would be ideal would be to set the status of the buttons within the setTitle() method?

This is my class:

```
class QuestionController: UIViewController {
    // OUTLETS //////
    // Outlet for the 'question' label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!


    // Outlet for the next button
    @IBAction func nextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flashcard = deck.getNextCard()
        questionTextView.text = flashcard!.question
        self.updateTitle()

    }

    // Outlet for last button
    @IBAction func lastQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flashcard = deck.getLastCard()
        questionTextView.text = flashcard!.question
        self.updateTitle()
    }

    // PROPERTIES /////

    var flashcard: Flashcard! // variable to hold current flashcard
    var deck = Deck(chapter: 0) // Defaults to first chapter until set


    // METHODS //////
    // Update the title with progress
    private func updateTitle() {
        let (chapter, question, totalQuestions) = deck.getProgress()
        self.title = "Chapter \(chapter) question \(question) of \(totalQuestions)"

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Holds deck of data
        flashcard = deck.getCurrentCard()
        questionTextView.text = flashcard!.question

        self.updateTitle() // Update the title with progress
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // Prepare flashcard item to be passed to the answer controller before segue
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let answerController = segue.destination as? AnswerController {
            answerController.flashcard = flashcard
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: on clicking the next and previous button check the count of the questions if it equals to last disable the next and if is the starting index then disable previous.

Answer (score 0):

Take outlet of the button use it. Like that:-

```
class QuestionController: UIViewController {

    @IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var btnNext: UIButton!
}
```

Comment: I tried that by control clicking from the button to the class to try and create a var outlet but it wouldn't let me, I thought this might be because I already have a func outlet for the button (to hold the actions for the button)?

Comment: The instance of button will be same in action and outlet both.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks I was able to create the outlets in the end. I then updated the updateTitle() method with the if statement below which updates the button status at the relevant points.

```
//
//  ViewController.swift
//  CISSP Flashcards
//
//  Created by Laurie Hocking on 24/04/2017.
//  Copyright © 2017 sQuidgy labs. All rights reserved.
//

import UIKit

class QuestionController: UIViewController {
    // OUTLETS //////
    // Outlet for the 'question' label
    @IBOutlet weak var questionTextView: UITextView!
    @IBOutlet weak var nextOutlet: UIButton!
    @IBOutlet weak var lastOutlet: UIButton!

    @IBOutlet weak var nextQuestion: UIButton!
    // Outlet for the next button
    @IBAction func nextQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flashcard = deck.getNextCard()
        questionTextView.text = flashcard!.question
        self.updateTitle()

    }

    // Outlet for last button
    @IBAction func lastQuestion(_ sender: UIButton) {
        flashcard = deck.getLastCard()
        questionTextView.text = flashcard!.question
        self.updateTitle()
    }

    // PROPERTIES /////

    var flashcard: Flashcard! // variable to hold current flashcard
    var deck = Deck(chapter: 0) // Defaults to first chapter until set


    // METHODS //////
    // Update the title with progress
    private func updateTitle() {
        let (chapter, question, totalQuestions) = deck.getProgress()
        self.title = "Chapter \(chapter) question \(question) of \(totalQuestions)"
        if (question == 1) {
            lastOutlet.isEnabled = false
            nextOutlet.isEnabled = true
        } else if (question == totalQuestions) {
            lastOutlet.isEnabled = true
            nextOutlet.isEnabled = false
        } else {
            lastOutlet.isEnabled = true
            nextOutlet.isEnabled = true
        }

    }

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
        // Holds deck of data
        flashcard = deck.getCurrentCard()
        questionTextView.text = flashcard!.question

        self.updateTitle() // Update the title with progress
    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }



    // Prepare flashcard item to be passed to the answer controller before segue
    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {
        if let answerController = segue.destination as? AnswerController {
            answerController.flashcard = flashcard
        }
    }

}
```